# What is an example of $R\otimes_R M$ not isomorphic to $M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Let $R$ be a ring and $f:R\rightarrow R$ be a ring homomorphism. ($f(1)=1$)

Let $R$ be given the left operation as the ring operation on $R$ and the right operation as $x•r=xf(r)$, so that $R$ is an $(R,R)$-bimodule.

Let $M$ be a left $R$-module and consider the extension of scalars $R\otimes_R M$.

What is an example of this such that $M$ is not isomorphic to $R\otimes_R M$ **as groups**?

Above hypothesis implies that $\iota:M\rightarrow R\otimes_R M:x\mapsto 1\otimes x$ is an injective group homomorphism, but I'm not sure whether this can be a surjection

Answer (score 2):

I think $R=F[X]$ ($F$ a field), $f: F[X]\to F[X]$, $X\mapsto 0$ and $M=F[X,Y]/(XY-1)\simeq F[X,X^{-1}]$ is an example. In this case, $R\otimes_R M=0$, while $M\neq0$.

Comment: Why $1\otimes 1=0$ ?

Comment: @user26857 :$1\otimes 1=1\otimes XX^{-1}=X•1\otimes X^{-1}=f(X)1\otimes X^{-1}=0\otimes X^{-1}=0$